# Amazon Mq TotalConsumerCount vs. CurrentConnectionsCount

Tags: monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-mq

trying to find the difference between these two metrics so that I would be able to establish the correct CloudWatch Alarm.

Purpose of my CloudWatch alarm is to detect, if my services connected successfully after rebooting the AmazonMq broker.

I have read the documentation on both and its pretty vague to me. Here is what I found:
**CurrentConnectionsCount** = The current number of active connections on the current broker.
**TotalConsumerCount**      = The number of message consumers subscribed to destinations on the current broker.

Any help would be great, thanks!

tried research and was not able to find any definitive answer in that regard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.